# Hyperlinks between merged PDFs produced from ODT and LaTeX

Tags: pdf, latex, libreoffice, embedding, pax

I include `auxfile.pdf` produced with libreoffice from `auxfile.odt` into `mainfile.pdf` produced with pdflatex from a LaTeX file `mainfile.tex` using `\usepackage{pdfpages}`.

Within `mainfile.tex` I am also defining hypertargets with `\hypertarget{keyword}{text}` using `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Hyperlinks defined in `mainfile.tex` as `\hyperlink{keyword}{some other text}` do work correctly in `mainfile.pdf`.

How can I define hyperlinks in `auxfile.odt`, then export to `auxfile.pdf`, and have them working in `mainfile.pdf` using the same keywords?

(I am using `\usepackage{pax}` to extract hyperlinks from `auxfile.pdf` before inclusion into `mainfile.pdf`)